# Android : AppCompatActivity ,adding search to toolbar

Tags: android, android-activity, material-design, android-search

I am trying to add search functionality to search an item from the list in an activity.I am trying it for android 5.1 and i want to support backward compatibility.I am using android-support-v7-appcompat.

MainActiviy :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Menu Xml :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:apk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.materialsearch.app.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="search"
    apk:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

adding toolbar to MainActivity Layout

```
mTooolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mTooolbar);
```

Styles.xml in values-v21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

I can see the search in menu item,but i don't see Edittext to enter text and search after clicking search.TIA

Answer (score 2):

After  long long search i found the error in the above code.As i am Using Support library to support backward compatibility, while defining the search widget in menu it should be defined as below

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

as

```
apk:showAsAction="always"
```